# New Table row every 4th loop

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do I create a new table row on every 4th loop in my Razor View?  This is creating a new row for each number before 4, and then quits creating new rows:

```
  @{
            int i = 0;
         }
         @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProgramIdList)
         {

          if((i / 4) == 0)
          {
              @:<tr>
          }
          <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="@item.ProgramId" id="@item.ProgramId" />   
         <label for="@item.ProgramTitle">@item.ProgramTitle</label>
         </td>
        if((i / 4) == 0) 
        {
        @:</tr>
          }
             i++;
         }
```

Comment: Look at what you're doing logically. (i / 4) will never actually equal 0 unless i == 0. The only reason it renders a few rows is because dividing two integers will always result in an integer and .NET has to round it that value to something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the modulo operator. For :

```
if((i % 4) == 0)
{
  @:<tr>
}
```

and

```
if((i % 4) == 3)
{
  @:</tr>
}
```

If the number of items doesn't divide into even rows, you would add the remaining cells and a closing row tag after the loop:

```
if ((i % 4) != 0) {
  while (i % 4) != 0) {
    @:<td></td>
    i++;
  }
  @:</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For those that hates the syntax higlight warning that appears with the code of the answer above, there is the solution (the mechanism is about the same):

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.MyItems.Count; i++)
    {
        var cells = 4;
        var item = ViewBag.MyItems[i];

        if ((i % cells) == 0)
        {
            @:<tr>
        }

        <td>
            @item.MyTextOrWhatever
        </td>

        if (i == (ViewBag.MyItems.Count - 1))
        {
            while ((i % cells) != 0)
            {
                @:<td></td>
                i++;
            }
        }

        if ((i % cells) == (cells - 1)) // aka: last row cell
        {
            @:</tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Each tag is in the right position (`<td>` inside `<tr>`, `<tr>` inside `<table>`), then your Visual Studio syntax highlighter will leave you in peace :-)

Comment: Thanks! Why does it want the `<tr>` tags escaped as plain text using the `@:` delimiter? I would've thought that would cause it to output `&lt;tr&gt;`

Comment: I think when your condition that fills out the row with empty cells runs, it brings `i` up to an even multiple of `cells`. Therefore the "last row cell" never gets added in that case because `i%cells` = 0, not `cells - 1`

Comment: @xr280xr consider that `i` is `base 0 index`, and `cells` means the total number of cells in a row, es: `i = 0, cells = 4;`. The first cell, or the cell number 1, corrisponding the index `0`.

Comment: @xr280xr also look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) about the `@:` syntax: _..The @: sequence indicates that the line of content that follows should be treated as a content block.._

Answer (score 0):

That the exact solution which 100% works.

```
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.data)
            {
                var cells = totalCells;


                if ((i % cells) == 0)
                {
                    @:<tr>
                }
                <td>
                    @item.Value
                </td>



                if ((i % cells) == (cells - 1)) // aka: last row cell
                {
                @:</tr>

                }
                i++;
            }
```