# Dynamic elements generated in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I'm trying to achieve the following in my TheseModels.cshtml:

```
<superdiv>
 <tinydiv>
 <tinydiv>
 <tinydiv>
<superdiv>
```

In other words, have 3 elements within a another n times.

What I tried so far is something along the lines of:

```
int i = 0;
@foreach (Model m in SomeModels)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        <superdiv>
    }
    i++;
    <tinydiv>
    </tinydiv>
    @if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        </superdiv>
    }
}
@if (i % 3 != 0)
{
    </superdiv>
}
```

However, this doesn't end well. What's the best way to achieve something like this?
The other way that I thought of would be to pre-package server side and have it return an array and each element containing 3 models.. but it seems stupid to do it that way and I wanted to have the display logic in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218467/1401886).

I guess you only need to add the razor html content prefix `@:` before the superdiv begin and end tag.

Also remove the `@` before the if inside the foreach because it’s illegal.

Comment: Thank you. The : did the trick. Follow up question, why did the : do the trick and why did stuff like @{..} or @.. fail ?

Comment: The trick is that @: is an escape for raw HTML and is not recognized by the interpreter; essentially your tag figure like a string so you don’t get the invalid html warning. By the way, the @{ } is a code block and must contains code and/or valid HTML. That’s all